# converting long decimal to scientific notation in symbolic expression Matlab

Tags: matlab

I know that if I want to convert a numerical expression to scientific notation, I shall use `eps()`. However, I have a symbolic expression where the results shall be displayed with scientific notation. For example:

the expression is stored in `result` which is:

```
result = 0.000002*x^2 + 0.000005*x + 0.000001
```

But, the desired result is:

```
2.0e-6*x^2 + 5.0e-6*x + 1.0e-6
```

When applying

```
result = eps(result);
```

I am getting this error:

> Error using eps
>
> Class must be 'single' or 'double'.

Notice that I have used `syms x;` to generate the previous expression.

My experience in Matlab is very shallow. Sorry if this question is so basic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution while searching. The solution is found [here](https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/180657-how-can-i-display-symbolic-expressions-using-decimals-instead-of-rational-fractions).

For short. It is by using `vpa(result,k)` where `k` is the number of significant digits.